# Replacing REST calls with GraphQL

Tags: graphql, nested-routes

I've recently read about the advantages (and disatvanteges) of GraphQL over Rest API.

I am developing a webpage that consumes several different Rest APIs and Soap services. Some of those services are dependent, meaning that a result from Rest1 will be passed as a parameter to Rest2 which will be passed to Soap service for a final return value.

From what I understood, GraphQL deals with multiple data sources and query nesting, but I have not yet understood if it will handle those nested **dependent** queries.

Can anyone that worked with several data sources that are dependent with GraphQL tell me if it can be done? My project should be up in 2 weeks and investing time in learning and setting up GraphQL and ending up not using it because it's not supporting my case would be a big failure for me.

**Note: the APIs and services are not mine, I am consuming them from an outside source**

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you haven't yet setup a GraphQL server. Once you do, you can see how this isn't too difficult. So, I'd recommend you setup your own server first. The Egghead Course, "[Build a GraphQL Server](https://egghead.io/courses/build-a-graphql-server)" got me started, but it's not free.

In essence, you'll be setting up your schema then defining how to resolve with data. When you resolve, you can setup an express server to query a database, or you can hit a REST interface, or hit your SOAP interface. How you retrieve the data is up to you, so long as you return it in compliance with your defined schema.

Hope that makes sense. Mocking up a mini app to demonstrate is possible, but since I don't have one handy, this is the best advice I can offer.